# XPath getting a node back using a max value

Tags: xslt, xpath

Say I have a bunch of elements like this:

```
<rs>
 <r>
  <roomID>ID2</roomID>
 </r>
 <r>
  <roomID>ID2</roomID>
 </r>
 <r>
  <roomID>ID3</roomID>
 </r>
 <r>
  <roomID>ID2</roomID>
 </r>
</rs>

<rooms>
 <room id="ID1">
  <val>200</val>
 </room>
 <room id="ID2">
  <val>100</val>
 </room>
 <room id="ID3">
  <val>200</val>
 </room>
</rooms>
```

I need to cycle through `rs`, and find the `r` that has the highest room value based on the `roomID`, which would be the third `r` element here (with roomID=ID3).

If I do this:

```
<xsl:variable name="max1" select="max(//room[@id=//r/roomID]/val)"/>
```

, I get 200, which is correct. But is there any way to get the specific ID back from this? If I just use the max value to get back the ID from the `room` elements, I can't know if it comes back from the same node. Something like this:

```
//room[val=max(//room[@id=//r/roomID]/val)]/@id[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this works:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//r[roomID=//room[val=max(//room[@id=//r/roomID]/val)]/@id]"/>
```

Seems a bit messy, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your xapth has only a small mistake Put the expression in parentheses `(...)` before selecting the first one `[1]`.
Try:

```
 (//room[val = max(//room[@id=//r/roomID]/val)]/@id)[1]
```